# Is the concrete nouns set larger than abstract one?

Tags: nouns, abstract-nouns

It is so difficult to get count over all nouns. Because of it I ask there, and it refers to my decision on how to research nouns in the near future. So, is the amount of concrete nouns larger than abstract one?

Comment: Where is "there" and what is the second "it" in the second sentence?

Comment: to get count over all nouns? What does that even mean? [number of nouns, not amount]

Comment: It is indeed difficult to get a count of how many nouns there are, in general; and also to determine how many nouns there are in any given text or speech. Counting is not something our grammars do automatically. First, you have to define what **you** mean by "noun", then distinguish by tests between concrete and abstract, in context, then count. Hard work. Good luck.

Comment: Are you including verbal nouns? Do you see uncountable nouns as concrete or abstract? Are you including proper nouns? Is a substantivised adjective a noun?

Comment: If you accept cardinal numbers as nouns, then they are abstract nouns, and are more numerous than the set of concrete nouns. The set of concrete nouns is finite, whereas the set of cardinal numbers is unbounded. But I don't think this gets to the heart of your question, so I'll just leave it as a comment.

Comment: The answer to this question probably wouldn't have any meaning. For example, there can be an infinite number of concrete nouns: pick any random fantasy novel and find the made-up name of a place, character, magical creature, spell, etc. That's a noun, though you may or may not find it in any particular dictionary. If you say, "Oh, I only want real nouns", then I challenge you to pick any map and find the name of a country or subdivision thereof - that is also a noun. If you say "Oh, I mean only nouns in the dictionary", then you have to pick one...

Comment: Just because there are an infinite number of *numbers* (unquestionably *abstract* nouns) doesn't imply that each one has a "dedicated" noun to identify it. The number ***three hundred and twenty-one***, for example, is trivially generated from a small set of "number nouns".

Comment: For what it's worth I just asked ChatGPT *are most English nouns concrete nouns or abstract nouns?* and it replied ***Most English nouns are actually concrete nouns.** Concrete nouns are nouns that refer to physical objects or things that can be perceived through the senses, such as "chair," "book," "dog," or "tree." Abstract nouns, on the other hand, refer to concepts, ideas, or emotions that are intangible, such as "love," "happiness," "justice," or "freedom." While abstract nouns are an important part of the English language, concrete nouns are much more common in everyday usage.*